# DSUM: How to define the criteria range using braces?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I think that it's easier to explain my problem with an example:

[image]

Based on the spreadsheet above, the formula `=DSUM(A4:D8,B4,A1:A2)` works, returning 20.

Why `=DSUM(A4:D8,B4,{"OrderID";">10567"})` does not work? (It returns #VALUE!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what's said about D-Functions on [this page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx), I think you need to have the criteria in a separate cell.

**EDIT:** If the goal of including the criteria in the formula is to make it more readable, you could work with [named ranges](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dsum.php) instead.

**EDIT 2:** *In response to your comments*.
It's not possible to do what you want (include the criteria in the formula) because of how the `DSUM()` function works. Take a look at the [documentation for `DSUM`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dsum.php) and compare it with [`VLOOKUP`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php):

> The syntax for the DSum function is:
>
> ```
> DSum( range, field, criteria )
> ```
>
> *range* is the range of cells that you want to apply the criteria against.
>
> *field* is the column to sum the values. You can either specify the numerical position of the column in the list or the column label in double quotation marks.
>
> *criteria* is the **range of cells** that contains your criteria.

Note the difference:

> The syntax for the VLookup function is:
>
> ```
> VLookup( value, table_array, index_number, not_exact_match )
> ```
>
> *value* is the value to search for in the first column of the table_array.
>
> *table_array* is two or more **columns of data** that is sorted in ascending order.
>
> *index_number* is the column number in table_array from which the matching value must be returned. The first column is 1.

As `DSUM` is looking for a **range of cells** that contain the criteria, there's nothing you can do to avoid passing it just that - a range of cells.

I think the best you can do is define your different criteria as named ranges, which will make it a lot easier to reference the different ones depending on what you want to do in the formula. Unfortunately, if the regular `SUM` function is not fast enough for you, there's not much else you can do - you *will* have to specify criteria in cells to use `DSUM`.

Comment: Are you sure? Why it works even in a VLOOKUP formula? 

=VLOOKUP("x", {1,"a";2,"b";"x","c"}, 2, 0) returns "c"

Comment: Thanks, but the goal is not to make it more readable. I need to define the criteria in the formula because I need to aggregate the data in several ways, and I don't want to create separate cells for everything.

Answer (score 1):

You may use SUMIF(A5:A8;>10567;D5:D8). A very useful and underused function.

The 2nd parameter may be a REF to another cell with the condition.

Answer (score 0):

From DSUM documentation

> Criteria   is the **range of cells** that
>   contains the conditions that you
>   specify. You can use any range for the
>   criteria argument, as long as it
>   includes at least one column label and
>   at least one cell below the column
>   label in which you specify a condition
>   for the column.

VLOOKUP uses an array of values.

> table_array  Required. The range of
>   cells that contains the data. You can
>   use a reference to a range (for
>   example, A2:D8), or a range name.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to filter by quantity also. I just want to define the criteria in the formula itself, and not with a range.

Comment: I could use {=SUM(IF(A5:A8>10567,B5:B8))}, but it is too slow.

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to define a range dynamically like an array?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, unless you try named ranges, but that will still have you using cells.

Answer (score 0):

Dsum sucks, try this: 
=SUMPRODUCT((A5:A8>10569)*(B5:B8))

Generally I would advise you not to hard code stuff like this, it's "bad practice", but as you like.